# Why isn't RandomPoint evaluating?

Tags: evaluation, random

Consider the expression

```
RandomPoint@
 BooleanRegion[#1 && ! #2 &, {Sphere[{0, 0, 0}], ConicHullRegion[{{0, 0, 0}}, {{1, 1, 1}}]}]
```

This does not evaluate to a random point in the region (in 12.3), and instead stays unevalauted. However, the argument is both `RegionQ` and `ConstantRegionQ`, as required by the documentation:

> `RandomPoint` can generate random points for any `RegionQ` region that is also `ConstantRegionQ`.

At first I thought it might be due to the degeneracy of the example, but using
`RandomPoint @ BooleanRegion[#1 && ! #2 &, {Sphere[{0, 0, 0}], ConicHullRegion[{{0, 0, 0}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}]}]`
fails as well. (Yet this `BooleanRegion` is bona fide: try putting `Region` in front.)

It doesn't seem to be a problem with `BooleanRegion`, as e.g. `RandomPoint @ BooleanRegion[#1 && ! #2 &, {Sphere[], Ball[{1,1,1}]}]` works.

What's happening here, and what's a suitable workaround?

**EDIT:** Looks like applying `DiscretizeRegion` before `RandomPoint` works! But why doesn't `RandomPoint` evaluate as expected?

Comment: In short it doesn’t know how to find them for this region so it comes back unevaluated. Discretizing gives a different region (but close approximation) and `RandomPoint` knows how to work with meshes.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

I found an example to show the limitation of `RegionIntersection`.

```
reg = RegionIntersection[Circle[{0, 0}, {5, 4}], 
   Circle[{0, 0}, {2, 8}]];
(* EmptyRegion[2] *)
RandomPoint[reg]
dreg = RegionIntersection[DiscretizeRegion@Circle[{0, 0}, {5, 4}], 
   DiscretizeRegion@Circle[{0, 0}, {2, 8}]];
RandomPoint[dreg]
```

> `RandomPoint[EmptyRegion[2]]`

> `{-1.76789, 3.73945}`

**Original**

Maybe `ConicHullRegion` is numeric and `Sphere` is symbolic, so they need to coordinate. The last result seems depend on the structure of discretize region.

```
SeedRandom[1];
BooleanRegion[#1 && ! #2 &, {Sphere[{0, 0, 0}], 
   Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}]}] // RandomPoint
RegionDifference[Sphere[], 
  Triangle[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}]] // RandomPoint
RegionDifference[Sphere[], 
   ConicHullRegion[{{0, 0, 0}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}]] // 
  DiscretizeRegion // RandomPoint
```

> `{0.245529, -0.968234, 0.0473094}`

> `{-0.528872, 0.54312, -0.652162}`